# pyinstaller create .exe file - UPX not available

Tags: python, pyinstaller

pyinstaller --onefile Test2
3411 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.4.1
3411 INFO: Python: 3.9.12 (conda)
3441 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
3442 INFO: wrote C:\Users\bbrouns\Documents\Test2.spec
3445 INFO: UPX is not available.
script 'C:\Users\bbrouns\Documents\Test2' not found

Trying to create a .exe file and this is what I get.
Also if I use Test2.py, its the same.

What is wrong?

Comment: The UPX is not available message is just informative, it has nothing to do with the error.  The error is that it cannot find Test2  make sure that Test2 is actually located in `C:...\Documents`